# Modify inline styles added by jquery isotope

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, jquery-isotope

I am modifying a theme to work with RTL.
On a gallery page there are certain inline styles added to elements probably by isotope because you can filter the pictures by their type.

html source

```
<div class="met_recent_work col-sm-4 branding">
```

resulting html in browser

```
<div class="met_recent_work col-sm-4 webdesign isotope-item" style="position: absolute; left: 0px; top: 0px; transform: translate3d(0px, 0px, 0px);">
```

How can I modify those properties?

Comment: Modifying isotopes added styles more than likely will break the isotope layout, FYI.

Answer (score 0):

Use `jquery` for this -

```
$('.met_recent_work').css('position', 'relative');
```

Answer (score 0):

You can change it with Jquery, when DOM loaded completely:

```
$(function(){
  $('.met_recent_work').css('position', 'relative');
});
```

Answer (score 0):

!important will override in-line styles.

```
.met_recent_work { position: relative !important; }
```